# Ошибка :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, gradle

Решил интегрировать в приложение appodeal, делал всё по инструкции, но результат всё тот же:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/widget/DefaultItemAnimator$7.class

Я гуглил этот вопрос, но решения так и не нашел. 
Вот gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.successdev.bookwindev.bookwin"
        vectorDrawables.generatedDensities = ['hdpi', 'xxhdpi']
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile project(':caldroidcustom')
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:3.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.6'

    compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: У вас дублирующиеся зависимости. Т.е. у какой-то либы их надо убрать. Ну или попробуйте убрать зависимость от support:recyclerview

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Попробовал убрать - результат тот же. 
Говорят, что помогать Rebuild Project, но не в моём случае ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой, решил ее так:

1) библиотеку appodeal к проекту подключаем через AndroidStudio IDE

2) Из gradle файла удаляем строку:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

и проверяем что есть строки

```
compile project(':cheetah-mobile-3.4.7')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/appodeal-1.15.9.jar')
```

для multidex надо там же в gradle файле в секции android -> DefaultConfig добавить:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

без него у меня тоже не собиралось.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о дублирующихся классах.

По умолчанию APPODEAL ZIP для multidex включает архив

```
android-support-v7-recyclerview-23.1.1.jar
```

и много других. Эта зависимость уже есть в вашем build.gradle и наличие jar излишне.
Просто удалите его из пакета "libs".